# How to recorder a RTSP Stream

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, rtsp, recorder

I'm using the `node-rtsp-stream` package and Websocket to make the transmission of my IP-Camera, and the visualization happens well, now I'd like to know how to record this transmission and I have no idea how to do this.

index.js in Server-side(NodeJS)

```js
const Stream = require('node-rtsp-stream'),
  stream = new Stream({
    name: 'Garage-Camera',
    streamUrl: `rtsp://${meu_ip}:1030/user=${user}&password=${pass}&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?`,
    wsPort: 5000
  })
```

in client-side

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="videoCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="jsmpeg.js"></script>
<script>
  const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000")
  const player = new jsmpeg(ws, {
    canvas: document.querySelector('#videoCanvas'),
    autoplay: true,
    audio: false,
    loop: true
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [node-rtsp-recorder](https://github.com/sahilchaddha/node-rtsp-recorder#readme) library and it's very simple to use it.

**recording example**

```js
     const Recorder = require('node-rtsp-recorder').Recorder
 
     var rec = new Recorder ({
         url: 'rtsp://192.168.1.12:8554/unicast',
         timeLimit: 60, // time in seconds for each segmented video file
         folder: __dirname,
         name: 'cam1',
     })
     // Starts Recording
     rec.startRecording();
 
     setTimeout (() => {
         console.log('Stopping Recording')
         rec.stopRecording()
         rec = null
     }, 300000)
```

**image capture example**

```js
     const Recorder = require('node-rtsp-recorder').Recorder
 
     var rec = new Recorder ({
         url: 'rtsp://192.168.1.12:8554/unicast',
         folder: __dirname,
         name: 'cam1',
         type: 'image',
     })
 
     rec.captureImage (() => {
         console.log('Image Captured')
     })
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This library might help [rtsp-video-recorder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rtsp-video-recorder).

In case of any question, suggestion or feature request you may contact me trough the [github issue tab](https://github.com/boonya/rtsp-video-recorder/issues)